# Is there a way to intercept java.io.File class in java agent

Tags: byte-buddy

all

For some reason, we want to intercept java.io.File class to add some log and do some check.

I tried to create a java agent with Byte Buddy to use Advice to do such things for some other class.

But it never work for class which is already loaded before agent premain. I am on byte-byddy 1.10.5

I also did some try use redefinition, or transform, but it's not work as well, not sure if I did something wrong.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable a retransformation of existing classes. Also, you need to define a custom ignore matcher as boot classes are not instrumented by default.

```
agentBuilder
  .with(RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
  .disableClassFormatChanges()
  .ignore(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, and it do works for me now, I did try something similar like this, does the order matter?

new AgentBuilder.Default().with(RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION).
        .disableClassFormatChanges().ignore(ElementMatchers.none())
        .type(ElementMatchers.named("java.lang.System")))
        .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder.visit(Advice.to(MyInterceptor.class).on(ElementMatchers.any())))
        .installOn(inst);

It works if I specified some methods, but it doesn't work if I use ElementMatchers.any()

Comment: I also try to use ElementMatchers.isConstructor() to listen constructor of File class, and it seems doesn't work as well.

Comment: Did you register an AgentBuilder.Listener to see if there is an error?